# Store data in MySQL or a PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project and I ended up with the table below:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default            | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------+-------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL               |  A_I  |
| user _id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL               |       |
| info          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL               |       |
| country       | tinyint(3)   | NO   |     | NULL               |       |
| date_added    | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00|       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------+-------+
```

Because I wanted to avoid storing countries as varchar all the time I thought I should use number IDs instead. My question is, would it be better to store the country IDs in a table where I would give a name to each one of them or do that in a php file? Countries won't change or anything. It will be a list of around 100 countries.

Thanks!

Comment: store them in a `countries` table and use a join to match them

Comment: I think you'll need a table "country" to make reference to that number IDs.

Comment: I would use a table and import this: https://github.com/raramuridesign/mysql-country-list/blob/master/mysql-country-list.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a seperate country table.

```
countries table
---------------
id
name
```

Then you can relate to the country ID in your table. That way you make sure only countries from your list are added and you don't need to store strings everywhere and you can easily change country names or addnew ones.

Comment: Will do that then. I just ended up with a ton of tables lol Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: NO - don't use surrogate keys when there is a perfectly good, efficient and standard mechanism for representing countries (ISO 3166)